# Why Help.ShowHelp(chmFileName); not working in mono on linux?

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, chm

Here I am trying to run .chm file when help is requested either using F1 key using `Form1_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent)` Why `Help.ShowHelp(chmFileName);` not working in mono on linux ? Where as it works good on visual studio, windows. Please help me to execute help on mono.

Comment: CHM is a Windows only file format. There is no native support on other operating systems for it, and that's why Mono guys do not attempt to support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void ShowHelpForLinux()
{
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "chmsee";
startInfo.Arguments = " " + help.chm + "::" + @"rootname//destination.htm";
Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

For mono c# help, this code will work.

By Samdoss

Comment: this code is working but, when when the file is opened it is showing about Chmsee

Comment: I know this is old, but in case anyone else has the same problem, as @UserCSharp pointed out the Arguments in the accepted answer do not work.  I use xchm instead chmsee, when what you need is "-c topicId help.chm", where topicId is an int (as defined in your Map.h file).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the relevant API calls aren't implemented on Linux.

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/Help.cs The function is marked as [MonoTODO].